# Why does LINQ Date Column comparison not work?

Tags: linq, datetime, linq-to-entities

For a LINQ query like:

```
var entities = from Account p in context.Accounts
                           where p.LastTimeServerSettingsChanged > p.LastTimeDeviceConnected
                           select p;
```

the query that is generated is:

```
SELECT 
[Extent1].[Username] AS [Username],
[Extent1].[LastTimeDeviceConnected] AS [LastTimeDeviceConnected], 
[Extent1].[LastTimeServerSettingsChanged] AS [LastTimeServerSettingsChanged]
FROM [dbo].[Account] AS [Extent1]
WHERE [Extent1].[LastTimeServerSettingsChanged] > [Extent1].[LastTimeDeviceConnected]
```

And this does not work (no results).

And the following also generates the same SQL (hence no results also)

```
var entities = context.Accounts.Where(k => k.LastTimeServerSettingsChanged > k.LastTimeDeviceConnected).Select(k => k);
```

My question is why, and how can this query be performed (using LINQ)?

Comment: What are you trying to do? How would you write the SQL?

Comment: ...and you have *verified* that there is data that meets the criteria in the database where the query is executed?

Comment: Fredrik, you are absolutely right. I was running the query on a wrong database. I shall give myself some minus marks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above code works fine. I was hitting the wrong database and hence was getting the wrong result. GIGO. QED.